# How do I respond to Mod question?

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged [an answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/272082/88313) as abusive because of the derogatory language the author used to reference another user (the answer has since been edited but you can see the original text in the edit history).  I was using [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor/58035#58035) as my guide for what constitutes 'abuse'.

The flag reviewer responded with a question to me:
[image]

I don't want the reviewer to think I'm an idiot and I want them to know why I flagged it as I did (I don't want to argue that it was declined, that's within their right).

How do I respond and answer the question?

Comment: You found the correct spot to discuss moderation! Thanks for asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically flags are for things where the normal tools cannot fix the issue. In this case, an edit handled it which is why the flag was declined.

Keep in mind, when we review flags we see the current post and not the original. The behavior was both rude and offensive so I've suspended the account in question temporarily.

Comment: Thanks @bmike.  I didn't know the post was edited by the time it was seen by a Mod.  I guess my goal was to bring Mod attention to that author's behaviour and that should've been done using the 'moderator intervention'  flag, instead.  Is this the correct forum to addressing flag questions asked by a Mod?

Comment: Yes @fsb - all moderation questions can be asked here - even if you have a private question you can ask for a private mod chat room to be set up. Asking here pings all the site mods much faster than by chat or pinging us with a flag.

Comment: However in this case surely flag as abusive should do more than just do an edit - the OP needs to have action taken against him even if the reason was edited out by someone else.

Comment: Nope. The referenced guide is clear: "If an otherwise valid post contains vulgar words as an expression of frustration, edit the bad part out instead of flagging the entire post as rude or abusive."